# Strip non-numeric or decimal from JavaScript INLINE

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to modify an existing line of JavaScript that I use often to format dollar amount entries in form fields so that the cents are displayed, even if not entered. I have used this for years:

```
<input maxlength="7" name="dollarvalue" size="8" onChange="javascript:this.value=parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);" />
```

...but it breaks if anything is entered other than numbers or a decimal...so I thought I could probably add a `str.replace()` to filter out the disallowed characters. It needs to be completely self-contained (as shown) so that I can easily add this one line `onChange` to a form field as needed. I got as far as this below, which still works for numbers, but is not stripping out other stuff. What am I doing wrong?

```
<input maxlength="7" name="dollarvalue" size="8" onChange="javascript:this.value=parseFloat(this.value.replace('/[^0-9\.]+/g','')).toFixed(2);" />
```

Comment: Why on earth are you doing this inline? Do you _like_ having to duplicate the same code everywhere? I know you want to be able to add it to any form field, but surely you could make it a library function? Note that your regular expression currently allows multiple decimal points. Note also that you don't need to say `javascript:` because the browser is already expecting JavaScript in any event handler; that prefix is only required (and only makes sense) if you use it in the `href` attribute of a anchor tag - which you really shouldn't be doing anyway, but that's a discussion for another day.

Comment: why the down-vote?  i use this typically at most one time per page...and want something i can easily just paste in on any project i am working on without requiring other dependencies.  I am not abusing it, i simply need something ultra-portable to use in the occasions that i want to quickly format an incoming value.

Comment: I didn't downvote (I've never downvoted, and in any case I don't think your post deserved a downvote). People often downvote without good reason - a few hours ago somebody did so on an old question and answer of mine without leaving an explanation. Some people just don't understand the concept of _constructive_ criticism...

Comment: hrmm...oh well...okay.  Anyway, i have this working now (i removed `javascript:`) as you suggested and took out the quote marks as pointed out by @KaeVerens below.  For now it is only in use on one single page of one single project in one single field...so this really is the best way (i think) to handle it in my specific circumstance.  Hopefully it may be helpful to others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There shouldn't be quotes around the regular expression. You'll need to change

```
this.value.replace('/[^0-9\.]+/g','')
```

to

```
this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,'')
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be quoting your regular expression, so the whole second line should be:

```
<input maxlength="7" name="dollarvalue" size="8" onChange="javascript:this.value=parseFloat(this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,'')).toFixed(2);" />
```